# Output of #check Nat.add

Tags: lean

the output of

`#check Nat.add`

seems to be garbled - the result looks like

`Nat.add (a✝a✝¹ : Nat) : Nat`

Version:  4.0.0-nightly-2023-07-06, commit c268d7e97bb0, Release

How can I make sense of this output?

Note: as of version 4.8 this change has been reverted, and the output looks like, as expected,
`Nat.add : Nat → Nat → Nat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only part of that output that is actually not printed the way we would want (due to pretty printer limitations) is the lack of space between the two identifiers; it should have said:

```
Nat.add (a✝ a✝¹ : Nat) : Nat
```

What it means is that `Nat.add` is a function with two arguments of type `Nat` and which returns a value of type `Nat`. The arguments are given names, but the names themselves are "hygienic" a.k.a not expressible directly, which is indicated in the pretty printer using a dagger symbol after the identifier. (This most likely indicates that the function was written without naming the arguments, as in `def Nat.add : Nat -> Nat -> Nat := ...`.) If the function had been declared with named parameters, you would see them here:

```
def foo (x y : Nat) : Nat := x + y

#check foo
-- foo (x y : Nat) : Nat
```

The names of the parameters are relevant because you can use them in code:

```
#check foo (y := 2) (x := 1)
-- foo 1 2 : Nat
```

Comment: What is the meaning of the 1 next to the second dagger? Also I guess there is a need to update the documentation, as it still mentions that in this case the output is  Nat -> Nat -> Nat

Comment: what documentation? The 1 next to the dagger is because there are two inaccessible variables here, and superscript numbers are used to disambiguate them.

Comment: The documentation is:
https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean4/dependent_type_theory.html
in section "Simple Type Theory"

Comment: The display has been reverted to the old style as of Lean 4.8

Comment: I will leave the answer as is since it wouldn't be an answer to the question otherwise.